# Can I measure the voltage noise with True RMS function

Tags: rms, snr, noise-spectral-density

I have a measurement setup with which I want to measure high voltages. Now I want to evaluate the noise this setup produces (preferably in V/sqrt(Hz)). I short circuited the input and I am now measuring the output of the setup produces. The output signal is not terminated (HighZ).
I am using a picoscope so I can digitally filter the signal and calculate the True RMS values of them.
The "signal" is already filtered out by using ac mode. Am I correct in the assumption that I now can use these true rms values as my voltage noise?
[image]

Comment: Should be. If you have no DC component then RMS=True RMS.

Comment: You can always save the waveform eg in ASCII or excel and calculate rms using math in time or frequency domain. Pay attention that you have two repetitive glitches, so definition of noise you want to apply may vary: really everything goes into noise calc or only incoherent components?